# Improving the query performance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table for document storage. The document could be either a book with multiple pages, page numbering starting from 0 or a singlepage document.

```
Category
Title
PageNo - integer
LineNo integer
Key
Value
```

I need a query that pulls all the keys from the table that belong to one-page documents and Category1.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Key 
FROM Materials
WHERE Category='Category1' and Key NOT IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT Key 
from Materials 
WHERE Category='Category1'
and PageNo>0)
```

The query works fine excluding all the materials that have more than 1 page. I wanted to rewrite the query to improve it in terms of performance and also to avoid any repeating code such as keyword DISTINCT and WHERE clause, if possible. I'd appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

Comment: You could avoid repeating the category parameter/literal value ('Category1') by correlating in the inner query `from Materials m2 where m2.Category = Materials.Category`. But I think the `group by` answer is better anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if PageNo is not null

```
SELECT Key 
FROM Materials
WHERE Category='Category1'
GROUP BY Key 
having  max(PageNo) <= 0
```

if PageNo is nullable

```
SELECT Key 
FROM Materials
WHERE Category='Category1'
GROUP BY Key 
having  max(isnull(PageNo,0)) <= 0
```

Comment: Or perhaps just `having count(*) = 1` is better to avoid the need to care how the page numbering works.

Comment: @shawnt00 If that is what they want then yes

Answer (score 1):

Remove the second DISTINCT

- Adding DISTINCT will add additional table scans

Query should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Key 
FROM Materials
WHERE Category='Category1'
 and Key NOT IN 
(SELECT Key 
from Materials 
WHERE Category='Category1'
and PageNo>0)
```

Comment: There's a change that Query Optimizer will ignore that DISTINCT statement anyway. Or add by itself,

Comment: why is there a need for PageNo < 1?

Comment: @ElenaDBA - Removed..  Thanks.